# Make hyphens come after alphabet when sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

Is there a way to make an exception for hyphens to get sorted to come after alphabet?

My current code:

```
 students.OrderBy(x => x?.Grades[2].Letter).ToArray()
```

In this case, the Geography colum has been sorted:
[image: In this case, the Geography colum has been sorted:]

Answer (score 2):

This is what came to my mind first (assuming `Letter` is of type `char`):

```
var sortedStudents = students.OrderBy(x => {
        var letter = x?.Grades[2].Letter
        // Handle null
        if(letter == '-')
            return letter + 77; //increasing the character code so it comes after all letters
        return letter;
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: It is important to show that you need to assign the result of this sort to another list or array of students

Comment: I don't think this will cause any problems. At the end of the sorting hyphens will be shown as hyphens (not a different character).Here is an example that I tested with:
`A 65
C 67
Z 90
a 97
g 103
z 122
- 45`

Comment: Oh, yes, ofc :) I copy-pasted it and forgot to add it. I will edit right away.

Comment: Just realized that I'm using string and not characters. Can this be implemented for strings as well? Changing everything to char will mess up at multiple places...

Comment: @Sandro In this case you better use the solution that @Avadh Vashisth suggested below. Implement your own `int compare(string a, string b)` method and use it to sort your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your custom sort function as shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<char> charList = new List<char>{
          'C',
          'B',
          'D',
          'A',
          '-'
        };
        
        charList.Sort((c1, c2) => compare(c1, c2));
        
        foreach(var a in charList){
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
    
    public static int compare(char a, char b){
        if(a == b)
            return 0;
        else if(a == '-')
            return 1;
        else if(b == '-')
            return -1;
        return (a < b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
-
```

Modify the function `compare` according to your need.

I could have written function `compare` directly inline, but kept it separate to make the explanation simple.

Comment: How can this be done using an array instead of lists?

Comment: Also, is it possible to have it as a string, rather than char? I tried to swap the char to string, as well as changing the '' to "", but get "Operator '<" cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Comment: You can use String.Compare function. [String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Array also have similar function [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1) for sorting.

Comment: I'm using array.sort over here. But how can it sort the hyphen to be last? Array.Sort(students, (x, y) => String.Compare(x?.Grades[2].Letter.ToString(), y?.Grades[2].Letter.ToString()));

Comment: Create a separate compare function like shown above. Use String.Compare instead of '<' operator.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seem to work for me:

```
students = students
.OrderBy(x => x?.Grades[2].Letter)
.OrderBy(x => x?.Grades[2].Letter.Contains("-"))
.ToArray();
```